# Recursive binary search for find max in bitonic list in Python

Tags: python, recursion, binary

Beginner here, I hope someone can help me. I wrote a code in Python to find the max value from a bitonic list by using a recursively called binary search. The problem is, that I get a max recursion depth error and I just can't figure out, why.

basically Im reducing the length of the list by removing elements that are lower than my mid value. So, anyone has an idea, what is wrong here? Thanks in advance!

```
def max_bitonic(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
    else:
        mid = a[len(a) // 2]
        if mid >= a[((len(a)//2)-1)]:
            del a[0 : ((len(a)//2)-1)]
            max_bitonic(a)
        else:
            del a[(len(a)//2)]
            max_bitonic(a)
```

Comment: Not related to the fix but you need to do `return max_bitonic(a)`, otherwise you're returning `None` instead of the value you want.

Comment: What if `len(a) == 2` and `mid >= a[((len(a)//2)-1)]`?

Comment: if len(a)==2, mid should be a[1] and  a[0:0] should be deleted, right? so the next time the program is running, len(a)==1 and itll return a[0]

Comment: Try to run this: `a = [0,1,2]; del a[0:0]; print(a)`

Comment: https://eval.in/922955

Comment: `print a[0:0]` gives `[]`, so nothing gets deleted, and you're stuck doing taking the same branch with each recursion.